# can't get the href value of the a tag while scraping using selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, xpath

I am trying to scrape some data from this page
[enter link description here](https://community.vortal.biz/public/?SkinName=conseileurope&Language=fr&AuthorityVat=77886008000010APE990Z&currentLanguage=en)

I am able to get some data but can't get the href value of the tag.  you can see it in the picture as well. please note href attribute is not present in the tag.

how can I get the href value because that is what I really want to have.
[image]

Comment: Seems a `react` website. The website is generated dynamically from javascript.

Comment: If you click the tag you could just use driver.current_url after you switch windows to it.

Comment: @ArundeepChohan great Idea gonna do that